# Is there is an easy way to restrict web page to certain users?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have some pages that should only be used by admin personnel.

Apart from asp.net membership services, or creating my own bespoke login solution, is there any quick and simple techniques to restrict certain pages from users?

All advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There are but they are not secure.**

You can add on session a flag that this user is permitted to see the extra pages, and on the extra pages simple check if this flag is set, or else you redirect him.

By add this on a master page, you can make it only ones.